# Rake spec runs the test suite, rspec spec causes a Mysql2::Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

Rails 4.2.5 on OSX 10.11.4, MySQL 5.7.11

Running `rake spec` runs the test suite (good), `rspec spec` causes a `Mysql2::Error` (bad).
My limited understanding is that `rake spec` and `rspec spec`should be doing exactly the same thing.

I am hoping this will be seen by someone who has experienced this before.

This strange behavior is happening after a pull from remote that added a lot of new features developed by a remote team. Now the test suite that I am developing for the application acting very strangely.

`rspec spec` fails with:

```
…/lib/mysql2/client.rb:107:in `_query': Mysql2::Error: No database selected: SHOW TABLES (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

I have seen this error before usually with straight-forward issues in the database.yml file, yet that file hasn’t changed and is referencing the correct databases.

I verified via mysql shell that the test database exists and has all of the expected tables.

The app runs fine in the development environment.

Running `rake spec` did nothing until I added `require "spec-rails"` to application.rb which was not necessary before the git pull described above.

Running `rake db:test:prepare` works smoothly and I verified that it is setting up the schema as expected.

I have dropped and re-created the test database just to make sure.

I have stopped and restarted the mysql server

While `rake spec` works it is MUCH slower that it was before the pull.

Comment: What is `rspec`? Are you using bundler or a binstub? If a binstub, did it change recently?

Comment: Using bundler. Rspec is a DSL for testing: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.

Comment: I meant what is the path to the `rspec` executable? If it's a binstub checked in to your project, and it changed recently, the problem could be there.

Comment: I am not familiar with binstub so cant really answer that part. Nothing about rspec is checked into the repo.
I forgot to mention that I am using rvm.
Rspec is located: /Users/fname.lname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@lux/bin/rspec